# How to ensure that my macOS app always launches with the sidebar open?

Tags: macos, user-interface, swiftui, sidebar

I've created my macOS app (using SwiftUI and `NavigationView`.) The navigation view can be resized by a user, and worst of all, if he/she drags it too far to the left, the sidebar (on the left) will be closed and when they open the app again, it won't be shown.

I've found a way to add this button to "toggle" the sidebar:

```
var body: some View {
    
    NavigationView() {
        //...
    }
    .toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigation) {
            Button(action: toggleSidebar, label: {
                Image(systemName: "sidebar.leading")
            })
        }
    }
}

func toggleSidebar() {
        NSApp.keyWindow?.firstResponder?.tryToPerform(#selector(NSSplitViewController.toggleSidebar(_:)), with: nil)
}
```

That is added here:

[image]

But that may be very confusing for a user if the sidebar on the left is gone, which is used to switch between main views in my app.

My question is, how do I ensure that the sidebar is always open when the app launches?

Or, alternatively, how do I prevent it from being resized?

Comment: NavigationView isn’t capable, only NavigationSplitView

Comment: you can do it via introspection / the introspect for swiftui library on github

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible to do with `NavigationView`. If you can, use `NavigationSplitView`

```swift
@main
struct StackViewSampleApp: App {
    @State var visibility = NavigationSplitViewVisibility.all

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: $visibility) {
                Color.red
                    .navigationSplitViewColumnWidth(300)
            } content: {
                Color.blue
            } detail: {
                Color.green
            }
            .navigationTitle("Always Open Split")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not the answer to my question, but it's helpful to know. Thanks.

Comment: > "This isn't possible to do with NavigationView. "
Unfortunately that is the answer to your question.  Even poking around the view hierarchy and manually setting constraints may not work reliably because of SwiftUI's update mechanism

Comment: @nteissler it works reliably for a while now on macOS via view introspection. it's a solid option.